# ASP .NET Core MVC JQuery AJAX - problem with getting data to view via controller api using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

When the line getJSON is executed and there is routing to for example: https://localhost:44338/ArticleApi/GetNextArticles?id=12&quantity=2&filterName=Odziez

I get error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Cannot find this page on localhost

**GetNextArticles method in my ArticleApiController:**

```
 [HttpGet("{id}/{count}/{filterName}")]
    public IEnumerable<Article> GetNextArticles(int id, int count, string filterName)
    {
        return _articleRepository.GetNextArticles(id, count, filterName);
    }
```

**in my view (.cshtml file):**

```
 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetNextArticles", "ArticleApi")' + "?id=" + last + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&filterName=" + filterCategory, function(data, status) {
     
                    for(var index in data) {etc...}}
```

**GetNextArticles method:**

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetNextArticles(int id, int count, string filterName)
    {
        List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();

        var categoryId = _context.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryName == filterName).Select(c => c.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {


            var foundArticles = _context.Articles.Where(a => a.CategoryId == categoryId && a.ArticleId == id + i + 1).ToList();

            if (foundArticles.Count() == 0)
            {
                return articles;
            }

            var article = foundArticles[0];

            if (article != null)
            {

                article.Category = _context.Categories.Find(article.CategoryId);

                articles.Add(article);
            }
            else
            {
                var nextArticles = _context.Articles.Where(a => a.CategoryId == categoryId && article.ArticleId <= id + i + 100).ToList();

                if (nextArticles.Count != 0)
                {
                    id = nextArticles.Min(a => a.ArticleId);

                    articles.Add(nextArticles.Where(a => a.ArticleId == id).First());
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return articles;
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the `[HttpGet("{id}/{count}/{filterName}")]` line

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, that helped. Thanks.

Comment: @freedomn-m actually - I can't load api definition on swagger after deleting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `[HttpGet("{id}/{count}/{filterName}")]` in your Api, The Url passed into this api must be `https://localhost:44338/ArticleApi/GetNextArticles/Id/count/filterName`.

So, If you don't want to change the `$.getJSON(..){...}` in the View, You can change the api like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Article> GetNextArticles([FromQuery]int id, int count, string filterName)
    {
        return _articleRepository.GetNextArticles(id, count, filterName);
    }
```

**You can see the Api works fine and it can be loaded in Swagger as well**

[image]
[image]

Comment: If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks you, very much.

Comment: I get this error:

 AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

ShopIdentity.Controllers.ArticleApiController.Get (ShopIdentity)
ShopIdentity.Controllers.ArticleApiController.GetNextArticles (ShopIdentity)

Comment: In your api controller, There are two [[HttpGet] methods , you should give they different names to distinguish. If you don't want to change `$.getJSON(..){...}`'s Url,  you can use  [[HttpGet("get")] in `get` method

Comment: Yes, I have managed to do this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, you could validate the names of the parameters that you are sending. Reviewing the code I realize that one of them is sent with the name "quantity" and in the controller you call it "count"

Comment: It didn't help :|